# Read non ASCII character with pandas with type str

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I need to read character `"ò"` and many other non-ASCII character as `str` from excel file using pandas.

If I do this `character = "ò"` the character is of type `str` and it is fine.

But when I read excel `df = pd.read_excel(open(excel_path, 'rb'))` it is of type `unicode`. If I do `df = pd.read_excel(open(excel_path, 'rb'), dtype='str')` I get `{ValueError}Unable to convert column to type string`.

I spent a lot of hours searching but nothing helped; the requirements are `Python 2.7` and the character to remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the read_excel command:

```
engine='xlsxwriter'
```

Comment: This engine is not supported in pandas 1.05. I tried `xlrd` and it doesnt make the unicode str.

Comment: Why don't you upgrade pandas?